# Python: How is this error being generated and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm working on a simple server based guessing game. Part of the client side of things is that there is an ssl secured admin client that can access the server to request information. I am currently trying to add the certificates and stuff to the requests however when running the (admittedly incomplete) file I get a '`ValueError: file descriptor cannot be a negative integer (-1)`' at line 65 of the following code:

```
import select
import socket
import ssl
import random

def CreateGame():
    number = random.randrange(1,21,1)
    ##print(number)
    return number

def Greetings():
    member.send("Greetings\r\n".encode())

def Far():
    member.send("Far\r\n".encode())

def Close():
    member.send("Close\r\n".encode())

def Correct():
    member.send("Correct\r\n".encode())

def AdminGreetings():
    member.send("Admin-Greetings\r\n".encode())

def Who():
    responce = ""
    for connection in clientList:
        if connection != member:
            responce += str(clientList[connection])
    member.send((str(responce)).encode())
    member.close()
    reader_list.remove(member)
    del clientList[member]

def GameLogic(mNumber):
    if("Guess: " + str(mNumber) + "\r\n" == guess):
        Correct()
    elif(("Guess: " + str(mNumber-3) + "\r\n" == guess) or
         ("Guess: " + str(mNumber-2) + "\r\n" == guess) or
         ("Guess: " + str(mNumber-1) + "\r\n" == guess) or
         ("Guess: " + str(mNumber+1) + "\r\n" == guess) or
         ("Guess: " + str(mNumber+2) + "\r\n" == guess) or
         ("Guess: " + str(mNumber+3) + "\r\n" == guess) ):
        Close()
    else:
        Far()



#client socket
s1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s1.bind(('',4000))  
s1.listen(5)
#admin socket
s2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s2.bind(('',4001))  
s2.listen(5)

reader_list = [s1,s2]
clientList = {}
mNumber = CreateGame()

while True:
    (read,write,error) = select.select(reader_list,[],[])

    for member in read:
        if member == s1:
            (read,write) = s1.accept()
            reader_list.append(read)
        elif member == s2:
            (read,write) = s2.accept()
            reader_list.append(read)
            sslSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(member,
                                    keyfile="5cc515_server.key",
                                    certfile="5cc515_server.crt",
                                    server_side = True,
                                    cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                                    ca_certs="5cc515_root_ca.crt")
        else:
            try:
                message = member.recv(4092).decode()
                sockAddr = member.getsockname()
                if(message == "Hello\r\n"):
                    addr = str(sockAddr[0]) + " " + str(sockAddr[1]) + "\r\n"
                    clientList[member] = addr
                    if (sockAddr[1] == 4001):#is using port 4000
                        try:
                            ssl_s = ssl.wrap_socket(member,
                                                    keyfile="5cc515_server.key",
                                                    certfile="5cc515_server.crt",
                                                    server_side = True,
                                                    cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
                                                    ca_certs="5cc515_root_ca.crt")
                            ##handshake stuff
                            AdminGreetings()
                        except:
                            break
                    else:
                        Greetings()
                elif(message == "Who\r\n"):
                    ##handshake stuff
                    Who()
                else:
                    ##print("try and assign guess")
                    guess = message
                    ##print("game logic")
                    GameLogic(mNumber)
            except:
                print("recv failed")
                member.close()
                reader_list.remove(member)
                del clientList[member]
                break
```

I understand that without the crt and key this cant really be debugged, but since nothing is making changes to the reader_list[] i dont see why it goes from 2 to -ve...

anyway here is the other part (the admin client)

```
import socket
import select
import ssl

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
handshake = False
# send Hello
try:
    while handshake == False:
        print("create ssl socket")
        sslSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(s,
                                    keyfile="100297626.key",
                                    certfile="100297626.crt",
                                    server_side = False,
                                    ca_certs="5cc515_root_ca.crt")
        print("connect")
        sslSocket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 4001))
        print("send hello")
        sslSocket.write("Hello\r\n".encode())
    print("rec hello")
    sslSocket.recv(80).decode()
    sslSocket.send("Who\r\n".encode())
    print(sslSocket.recv(4092).decode())
except:
    print("Server Unavailable")
s.close()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: At what OS you running this code?

Comment: @Farseer Windows 7 64bit

Comment: select can't work with streams on Windows

Comment: "Note that on Windows, it only works for sockets;" The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html) seem to suggest that it works for sockets at least.  Can you check if the `socket.socket` calls returned valid file descriptors?

Comment: -but what causes `select.select` to fail?
-is there any way i can get this to work on windows?

Comment: @Rufflewind up until now the `select.select` calls have been working fine, its only since implementing the ssl that its started with the errors

Answer (score 0):

As line 65 is:

```
    (read,write,error) = select.select(reader_list,[],[])
```

One must infer that the error comes from passing a socket with a fd of `-1` to `select.select` in its read_list. Please run your code again but include the check that:

```
assert all(s.fileno() != -1 for s in reader_list)
```

Comment: adding this creates an assertion error, showing that it has something to do with the -1 being passed in by the sslSocket

Comment: This would not help if `s.fileno()` is `-1`, it would just change the error to an `AssertionError`.

Comment: It wouldn't but the issue is that the `-1` is coming from somewhere. And this would at least help track that down.